# "protocol Enumerable not implemented" Error on redirect with params

Tags: authentication, request, elixir, phoenix-framework

After Users are created on UserController :create, I'd like to redirect them to session_path(conn, :create) to have them logged in. But I cannot get the call working. This is what I tried:

```
def create(conn, %{"user" => user_params}) do
  changeset = User.registration_changeset(%User{}, user_params)

  case Repo.insert(changeset) do
    {:ok, user} ->
      conn
      |> put_status(:created)
      |> redirect(to:  session_path(conn, :create, Poison.encode!(user_params)))
    {:error, changeset} ->
      conn
      |> put_status(:unprocessable_entity)
      |> render(Prode.UserView, "error.json", errors: changeset.errors)
  end
end
```

It throws the following Error:

```
(Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol Enumerable not implemented for "{\"password\":\"s3cr3t\",\"email\":\"foo@barr.com\"}"
```

On this line:

```
|> redirect(to:  session_path(conn, :create, Poison.encode!(user_params)))
```

I should add the route for User and Session controllers is set to use json:

```
pipeline :api do
  plug :accepts, ["json"]
end

scope "/api", Prode do
  pipe_through :api
  resources "/users", UserController
  resources "/sessions", SessionController, only: [:create, :delete]
end
```

And SessionController create accepts user_params:

```
def create(conn, %{"user" => user_params}) do
  ...
end
```

Comment: Why are you passing `Poison.encode!(user_params)` there? Does your `:create` route accept a named parameter?

Comment: Just edited the question to add this info @Dogbert

Comment: Ah, that's a POST route; you cannot `redirect` to it.

Comment: ups. You are right @Dogbert 
Thanks